# Go to Symbol doesn't seem to work in VSCode for Sass files, how do I get it to work?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, ide

I have a `.scss` file and also I have the `Sass` extension installed but `Go to Symbol...` doesn't seem to understand the sass structure. When I type `@pre .super i` it shows no results. Am I missing some configuration or some extension?

[image]

Comment: try the opposite: goto symbol .super in pre.  "@.super pre"

Comment: @ABoston it doesn't seem to work all the way. For example if I have `.list-container .item:before` then trying to go the opposite direction `@&:before .item .list-container` only gets me to `.item` but not all the way to `.list-container`

Comment: the first example of `pre > .super` you wanted to get to the child symbol of `.super`. But now it seems the aim is to get to the parent symbol of `.list-container.` so there is no need to type the child `&.before.` but more helpful than anything doesn't your vscode provide autocompletion? mine provides all the nodes in the target file.

Comment: @ABoston The goal is to directlyl navigate to `pre .super i` without having to manually find it. Yes my vscode provides autocompletion but that does not mean I can simply search for `pre .super i` and it will `jump` to the definition. That is the issue here.